# numpy diff weird behaviour

Tags: python, numpy

I have a case of strange behaviour of numpy diff:

```
a = list(img_arr[y_coord_1,:])
print a
print np.diff(a)

>>[62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62, 63, 62, 96, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 98, 66, 63, 64, 64, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64, 65, 65, 64, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64, 64, 63, 63, 63, 63, 63, 64, 65, 65, 64, 63, 63, 63, 63]
>>[  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1 255  34   2   0   0   0   0   0   0  0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 224 253   1   0 255
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0 255 255   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0 255   0   0   0   0   1   1   0 255 255   0   0   0]
```

Now, when I run this in the terminal I get the correct answer of

```
array([  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,  -1,  34,   2,   0,   0,
     0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
     0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
     0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, -32,  -3,   1,
     0,  -1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   1,
     0,  -1,  -1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0,  -1,   0,
     0,   0,   0,   1,   1,   0,  -1,  -1,   0,   0,   0])
```

What sort of things can cause this - I am using a few other compiled libraries in this script, if this of relevance

Edit: I've just spotted that its the negative numbers that are wrong - and the upper limit is very suspicious. Looks like a dtype issue..

Comment: What is `a.dtype`? Is it `np.uint8` by any chance?

Comment: This is the correct problem. It is an overflow error - feel silly for not spotting it earlier. I assumed that the list command would convert back to python floats or something

Comment: Calling `list()` on an `np.uint8` array will just give you a list of `np.uint8` scalar values. You need to explicitly cast your array to a signed integer type.

Comment: yeah, i fixed it. ty

Comment: (For future readers: [`.astype()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.tolist()` is a better way of converting an array to a list (or nested lists).  It carries the conversion all the way down.  `list()` just iterates on one level.  And since an array is already iterable, I don't think `list(anarray)` does anything useful.

start with an array:

```
In [789]: z
Out[789]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=uint8)
In [790]: type(list(z)[0])
Out[790]: numpy.uint8
```

`list()` is the same as this list comprehension:

```
In [791]: type([i for i in z][0])
Out[791]: numpy.uint8
```

the correct list conversion

```
In [792]: type(z.tolist()[0])
Out[792]: int
```

Why were you using `list()` in the first place?  You didn't need it for `diff`.  If overflow is an issue, dtype conversion is better.

`np.diff` will turn a list back into an array before taking the differences.

```
In [793]: np.diff(z.tolist())
Out[793]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
In [794]: np.diff(list(z))
Out[794]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)
In [795]: np.diff(z.astype('int'))
Out[795]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
In [796]: np.diff(z)
Out[796]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)
In [797]: np.array(list(z))
Out[797]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=uint8)
```